# Flutter - Firebase: Iterate sublist in List<DocumentSnapshot>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to iterate a sublist within a DocumentSnapshot list to display it in a UI?

```
List<Widget> buildWidgets(List<DocumentSnapshot> widgetListSnapshot) {
    List<Widget> widgets = List<Widget>();

    widgetListSnapshot.forEach((element) {
      widgets.add(Widget(
        field: element.data()['sublist'],
        field1: element.data()['sublist2'],
        field2: element.data()['sublist3'],
      ));
    });
    return widgets;
  }
```

My model has this structure

```
class Widget {

  List<String> field;
  List<String> field1;
  List<String> field2;

  Widget({
    this.field,
    this.field1,
    this.field2,
  });
}
```

The exception it shows me is this

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List(String)'

Comment: First: Widget is a reserved word, so you should change the for your class. Second: we don't have enough info about structure of `widgetListSnapshot`. Third: Are you sure `element.data()['sublist']` is a `List<String>`?

Comment: 1. Yes i know its just to illustrate what i need to do. 2. Through a Stream <QuerySnapshot> I get the data from firestore and pass it as a parameter in the buildWidgets function. 3. Mmm, I'm not, thanks.

Comment: what does `element.data()['sublist']` print?